# Iphone app is working fine in both landscape and portrait mode but in ipad it only works in one mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, landscape-portrait

I made an ios app which is working fine in the iPhone in both mode either it is landscape or portrait by using the autorotation methods i used the following code

```
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    self.view=Landscape;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad* (90));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,320.0);
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    self.view=Landscape;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad* (-90));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480.0,320.0);
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    self.view=Portrait;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad* (0));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0);
} else
{
    self.view=Portrait;
    self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad* (180));
    self.view.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0);
}
```

}

But for the iPad its work only in one mode either landscape or portrait when i rotate the device it shows the blank white screen but if i don't rotate that it works pretty fine.
Kindly guide me as i am new to the iOS.

Answer (score 0):

One place to check would be on the Application target, general tab, Deployment info section.

Just below the Deployment Target and Devices selectors, you can switch between iPhone and iPad, then enable supported orientations with the checkboxes.

If you already have these setup correctly for both iPad and iPhone, then you'll probably want to look at how you've handled the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` or possibly the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods of your UIViewControllers

[image: The first place to look...]

Comment: If everything is configured to allow the orientations you want in those places, then you'll have to dive into how you handle rotations themselves, especially with the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods of UIViewController

Comment: Yes i have selected the universal but its not working fine in iPad. In iphone its working fine in both modes but in iPad it only works in one mode when i rotate the iPad the screen becomes blank white

Comment: Great! So now we know that you correctly support all orientations, and that something happens when you rotate, just not the something that you want. So let's take a look at how you implement rotation. Do you configure your view hierarchy in a nib, in code or both? Do you use auto-layout? Please post your code for any setup in code, and then post your code for willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and for didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
    
   
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

Comment: the above code that i already have posted in the code is of 


-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration